# Unit test for Validation of a String in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing

I want to check if a specific String cannot have more length than 5 chars, start with letter "S" and is all in Upper Case. (this is just an example)

Imagine that you have this kind of behavior multiply by 20 fields on an object.

I want to write a unit test that says that if_all_the_fields_are_correct_validation_should_return_true();

My questions are:

- Should I do this?
- If yes, asserts could be thousand because could exist multiple possibilities.What should be done in this situation?

I will test individually each field, but I prefer also to get an immediate result for all of my fields.

**UPDATE:**

My focus is not in the method of string validation. That is already made.

My question is:

- I need to do validatite several fields and when this fields pass on validation the final result will be ok.

Let´s make a simple example.

For instance I have an object called MyValid. Inside it I have a String, an Integer and a date.

On a class ValidationOfMyValid I have a method called isValid(String a, Integer b, Date c);

Example of asserts that needs to be done:

```
if_all_the_fields_on_My_Valid_is_Right(){
    assertThat(this.myValid.isValid("STACK", 12, "20081205")).isTrue();
    assertThat(this.myValid.isValid("STACK", "integer", "20081205")).isFalse();
    assertThat(this.myValid.isValid("stack", "ee", "20081205")).isFalse();    
}
```

As you can see, there are hundred of possibilities. What should be done in this case?

Comment: You could use a regex, e.g. `^S[A-Z]{1,4}$`, which would be a word no more than 5 characters, starting with `S`, followed by 1-4 more uppercase letters.

Comment: Also if the fields have that specific value generation bit, probably you should write a test for the method that creates this kind of string you want to get not the place where you will set it.

Comment: I would further encapsulate all unique regex in an enum, say {`ALPHANUMERIC`, `EMAIL`} etc., and declare a method such as `boolean validate(String s)`. That way you can reuse a common method of an enum across various fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection for this in your testcase. That's a kind of hack:

```
Class aClass = MyPOJO.class  ...//obtain class object
Field[] fields = aClass.getFields();

for(Field field: fields){
    if(field.getType() instanceof String){
        // Use whatever regex you have for assertions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small function:

```
boolean stringIsValid(String s) {
    return s.matches("S[A-Z]{1,4}");
}
```

Then I would make several asserts so failure the wrong value and its cause can be shown.